# code not exiting outer for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

My code isn't exiting my outer for loop even when I come to the end of my string and I cannot figure out why. From my understanding, my outer loop should stop after the fourth iteration.  Instead, it continues and then errors out at String inputString = input.next(); because there is nothing there.  Here is my code:

```
public class Exercise17 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "i think, therefore i am";
        vowelCount(string);     
    }
    public static void vowelCount(String s) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(s);     
        int[] vowelArray = new int[5];
        int aCount = 0, eCount = 0, iCount = 0, oCount = 0, uCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.trim().length() - 1; i++) {
            String inputString = input.next();
            System.out.println(inputString);
            for(int j = 0; j < inputString.length(); j++) {
                char c = inputString.charAt(j);
                System.out.println(c);
                if(c == 'a') {
                    aCount++;                   
                }else if (c == 'e') {
                    eCount++;                   
                }else if (c == 'i') {
                    iCount++;                   
                }else if (c == 'o') {
                    oCount++;                   
                }else if (c == 'u') {
                    uCount++;                   
                }               
            }               
        }
        vowelArray[0] = aCount;
        vowelArray[1] = eCount;
        vowelArray[2] = iCount;
        vowelArray[3] = oCount;
        vowelArray[4] = uCount;
        input.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vowelArray));    
    }
}
```

As an experiment I have tried to get rid of the -1 and make it just i < s.trim().length() as well as changing it to i < s.trim().length() -2, i < s.trim().length() -3, i < s.trim().length() -4, etc., all the way up to -10.

Comment: Why are you using a for-loop instead of `input.hasNext()`?

Comment: @azurefrog I plead temporary insanity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scanner.next()` reads content of the input string **word by word** (i.e. "i", "think", "therefore", "i", "am") but you are counting the outer loop **letter by letter** (with respect to the input string). So the `next()` call throws an exception when the input string is exhausted, after the fifth iteration.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is glaringly obvious now that you point it out.  Not sure what I was thinking. I probably need to step away and take a break.  Thank you for your help. As soon as the timer will let me I will mark as solved.

Comment: Sure :) And please think about what @azurefrog suggested as well!